# consolidate duplicate rows and add column in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I'd like to know how to consolidate duplicate rows in a data frame and then combine the duplicated values in another column.

Here's a sample of the existing dataframe and two dataframes that would be acceptable as a solution

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("test1", "test2", "test2", "test3"), col2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
df.ideal <- data.frame(col1 = c("test1", "test2", "test3"), col2 = c(1, "2, 3", 4))
df.ideal2 <- data.frame(col1 = c("test1", "test2", "test3"), 
                        col2 = c(1, 2, 4), 
                        col3 = c(NA, 3, NA))
```

In the first ideal dataframe, the duplicated row is collapsed and the column is added with both numbers. I've looked at other similar questions on stack overflow, but they all dealt with combining rows. I need to delete the duplicate row because I have another dataset I'm merging it with that needs the a certain number of rows. So, I want to preserve all of the values. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To go from `df1` to `df.ideal`, you can use aggregate().

```
aggregate(col2~col1, df1, paste, collapse=",")
#    col1 col2
# 1 test1    1
# 2 test2  2,3
# 3 test3    4
```

If you want to get to `df.ideal2`, that's more of a reshaping from long to wide process. You can do

```
reshape(transform(df1, time=ave(col2, col1, FUN=seq_along)), idvar="col1", direction="wide")
#    col1 col2.1 col2.2
# 1 test1      1     NA
# 2 test2      2      3
# 4 test3      4     NA
```

using just the base `reshape()` function.

Comment: Probably `aggregate(col2 ~ col1, df1, toString)` would be cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use `splitstackshape`

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)
DT1 <- setDT(df1)[,list(col2=toString(col2)) ,col1]
DT1
#    col1 col2
#1: test1    1
#2: test2 2, 3
#3: test3    4
```

You could `split` the `col2` in `DT1` to get the `df.ideal2` or

```
cSplit(DT1, 'col2', sep=',')
#   col1 col2_1 col2_2
#1: test1      1     NA
#2: test2      2      3
#3: test3      4     NA
```

or from `df1`

```
 dcast.data.table(getanID(df1, 'col1'), col1~.id, value.var='col2')
 #   col1 1  2
 #1: test1 1 NA
 #2: test2 2  3
 #3: test3 4 NA
```